# Configuring PyCharm with existing virtualenv

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I am trying to get PyCharm running using existing virtualenv setting. I have pointed my PyCharm project to python interpreter in existing virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/myproj/ in the following path

File -> Default Settings -> Default Project -> Python Interpreter

the project runs fine but the editor is still glowing RED on packages installed as part of the virtualenv.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: this was related to project structure rather than python interpreter. Adding the right content root solved it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To run PyCharm properly for your project, you need to set Python Interpreter and Python Structure correctly.

I had set Python Interpreter correctly but missed out on Python Structure.

Go to Pycharm->Preferences->your_project->Project Structure

Add the right content root

It has nothing to do with your working directory which you can set separately in your debug/run configuration

also don't forget to add environment variables you need and you should be good to go.

For Intellij Idea 2016.2, following is the path to add site-packages installed in virtualenv 
File -> Project Structure -> Sources -> "Use + button and add as Sources"

if hidden directory may is be visible, you may either change your view settings or copy paste the path to site-packages in virtualenv

Comment: a little clarification on "Add the right content to root".  What worked for me with an existing Python 2.7.15 virtual environment was this...
With <project folder> as root, I marked `<project folder>/src` as `Sources` (shows up blue in Pycharm 2018).
I had previously selected `<project folder>/Scripts/python.exe` as my interpreter.

Answer (score 9):

[image]
Dont click on `make available to all projects` and it will work. Otherwise it would give error saying -- `specify a different sdk name`

Comment: I had to click on the make available to even see the venv appear in the project interpreter

Comment: For windows 11, python 3.10 and previously created environment with ``python -m venv myenvironmentname`` this is the most straightforward answer. Just put the path pointing to python.exe that is inside the ``.\Scripts`` folder of the existing virtual environment.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu users:

```
Step 1: Go to: "File > Settings > Python Interpreter"
Step 2: Drop down the Python Interpreter options and select "Show All..."
Step 3: Click on the left top "+" symbol to add your virtual environment
Step 4: Under Virtual Environment, select "Existing environment"
Step 5: By clicking the three dots at right side, link to the python 
        interpreter of your virtual environment. 
        For me, the linking looks like this: "/home/varat/cv/bin/python3"
        My virtual environment name is "cv"
Step 6: Finally, click "OK"
```

After some loading, the pycharm will be working under your linked virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

I did what was specified by comiventor in the accepted answer, but also had to do what Brian W commented: **mark the root folder as a "Sources Root"**. This is done as follows:

- Right click on your root directory
- Look at the bottom for the option `Mark Directory as`
- Choose `Sources Root` (the folder icon color should change from gray to blue)

That's all!

Answer (score 2):

For [PyCharm 19.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2019.3/quick-start-guide.html#interpreter)

`Ctrl + Alt + S`   or `File / Settings`

then

`Project: your-name-project / Project Interpreter / Gear Icon / Add ...`

Choose `New environment`

in `Location:`

set your `path / to / venv`

Finally, you should see

Project Interpreter : `path / to / venv / Scripts / python.exe`