# Pycharm: Files inside virtual environment folder doesn't show up and cannot activate

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

I just started to use Pycharm but it doesn't recognize `Django`. I already created `virtualenv` folder in my project and want to apply it into my project but I don't understand how to do it.

What I did is go to Settings -> Project -> Intepreter -> and I tried to add `virtualenv` folder in my project but couldn't (apply button doesn't work). Instead I added `virtualenv/Scripts/python.exe` in my User folder. But nothing changed.

How can I do it?

Actually something changed. Scanning installed packages was too long but just finished and now warning message like

> Package requirement ...

But I already installed them into `virtualenv` in my project.

Files inside `/bin` doesn't show up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxHUi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring PyCharm with existing virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868806/configuring-pycharm-with-existing-virtualenv)

Comment: I checked `activate virtualenv` in my Settings/Tools/Terminal section  but virtualenv does't activate.

Answer (score 4):

To Add the existing virtual environment follow the steps in Pycharm IDE given below:

1. Go to File > Settings > Project Interpreter
2. Click on Gear Box Icon(Settings)
3. Click on **Add** option.
4. Select **Existing Environment**
5. Navigate to your virtual environment directory and select the **Python2.x/Python3.x** file from **bin** directory. e.g(`/home/username/.envs/django_project/bin/python2.7`)

Also, read help from [Jetbrains Community](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) for more info needed.

Comment: Actually all files inside `/bin` doesn't show. I attached the picture to my question. Please look.

Comment: By referring your attached image, looks like your virtual environment is not created properly. Which OS are you using and how you created the virtual environment? @user10661085

Comment: If you are using ubuntu OS, follow the steps from [link](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) to create virtualenv and using it on ubuntu.

Comment: Here is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW4mf.png) of files inside `/bin` for reference.

Comment: I created it on WSL. Ofc I can see a bunch of files inside it when I use text editor. Is it impossible to use WSL for Pycharm?