# Activating virtual env

Tags: python, django

I made a virtual environment ,I can activate it in command prompt, but it doesn't activate with my_venv2\Scripts\activate.bat and I cant activate it in pycharm's terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring PyCharm with existing virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868806/configuring-pycharm-with-existing-virtualenv)

Comment: hey, please attach some more information like what steps you take exactly and how your custom scripts look like

Answer (score 0):

Its ok. Just make sure you navigate directly into the folder containing the activate.bat file i.e

```
cd my_venv2\Scripts
```

then type `activate.bat` or `.\activate` and press enter