# Configuring an existing interpreter for Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I can't believe I've been using Pycharm for 8 years and I still can't reliably and easily configure an interpreter.  In any case, when I click the following button no changes in Pycharm occur:

[image]

Everything remains exactly as it was before I clicked the OK button. I should also add that the Python working environment works when I use it from terminal.  Also, the venv working environment does not appear in the following list when I hit the OK button as seen in image 1.

[image]

[image]

Also, no new interpreters appear in the drop down box above.  I should also add that I can't use venv4 because my computer recently crashed and I had to use a back-up service but the back-up service did not save my aliases and in venv it uses an alias to refer back to the Python engine, so venv4 cannot be used, which is why I created venv6.

[image]

In the box above venv6 appears but when I select it, again nothing happens as seen in the image below Pycharm is still requesting an interpreter.

[image]

Why am I not able to add the interpreter to Pycharm by clicking the button shown above?

Comment: Okay, but I don't see an actual (programming) question here? As in, you literally forgot to actually write a question in your post, [what problem do you need help solving](/help/how-to-ask)? Asking about common tools used for programming can be fine, but it still needs to be an actual question: what did you set out to do, what did you do, how did that not work, and fairly importantly: what did you already (re)search to solve this, what did you find, and how did none of those things work? (Remember, SO is your _last_ resort, so you're expected to have exhausted other options already).

Comment: When someone says: I do x and nothing happens, that implies that they're asking, why does nothing happen, but since that inference was not made, I'll reword it.

Comment: @Mike I think the problem is quite apparent here, even if there’s no literal question mark.

Comment: What I think would improve the question is if you didn’t rely solely on screenshots, but provided the paths and venv versions which are involved here as text as well.

Comment: This might sound really dumb, but you did click "OK" on your second last image right?

Comment: @Abdul, I did..

Comment: @deceze, the paths appear in the screenshots.

Comment: They do, but they’d be more readable and accessible if also provided as text, and as textual description. Generally we have the rule to never post text as images. In this case it makes sense to include screenshots of course, but a textual description would still help. On mobile for example these screenshots are tiny and need a lot of zooming in and out. And that’s not even scratching the surface of using a screen reader.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm project interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862363/pycharm-project-interpreter)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/33868806

Answer (score -1):

I decided to simply create a new project.  That solved the problem.  The glitch was probably due to the fact that I was using the settings provided by my backup service and since my backup service did not save the aliases or because they didn't fully save every file, an error was thrown.